# Export table of estat icc from Stata to LaTeX from multilple estimation

Tags: stata

I want to export my `estat icc` after `mixed` model regression into a single table as LaTeX format.

```
mixed InExp age i.n_gender  i.year||HHID:||city:,reml iterate(10)
estat icc // I want to store this as model1
mixed InExp age i.n_gender  i.year||HHID:||city: if group=="Target",iterate(10)
estat icc // I want to store this as model2
```

By having only ICC and standard error in parentheses below no coefficient from regression needed.

Something like this:

```
Class    |  Model1 | Model2
1-level     xxxx      xxxx
            (xxx)     (xxx)
2-level     xxxx      xxxxx
            (xxx)     (xxx)
```

Comment: I would ask on Statalist. Many more people there do this kind of thing than are active under the Stata tag here.

Comment: Now cross-posted https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1546396-export-table-of-estat-icc-to-latex-from-multilple-estimation

Comment: @NickCox As your suggestion, I put it there. Thank you